# Combo box only displaying one record

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a combobox in Excel VBA that it only displaying one record but it should display 7. I have debuged the code and I can see how the routine goes throught the code assigning all the entries in the list, but then only one is displayed.

Can someone tell me what am I missing.

```
SqlSelect = "SELECT distinct [country] FROM [Data]" 'there are 7 records returned in this query

Set AdoRst = New ADODB.Recordset
AdoRst.Open SqlSelect, WfmDbCn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText


With Me.cmbCountry
    .ColumnCount = 1 
    .ColumnWidths = "0;0;150"
    .BoundColumn = 1

    Do Until .ListCount = 0
        .RemoveItem (0)
    Loop
    i = 0
    Do While Not AdoRst.EOF
        .AddItem AdoRst.Fields(0).Value
        .List(i, 1) = AdoRst.Fields(0) 
        i = i + 1
        AdoRst.MoveNext
    Loop

    If .ListCount > 0 Then
        .ListIndex = 0
    Else
        .Value = Null
    End If
End With
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
.ColumnCount = 1 
.ColumnWidths = "0;0;150"
```

You declare only one column, and then set the width of 3. If you adapt like this:

```
.ColumnCount = 2 
.ColumnWidths = "150;0"
```

It should work. `Boundcolumn` is not really nessesary here. `.AddItem` adds a value to column 1; `.List(i, 1)` adds a value to column 2.

Comment: Thanks Jzz. Fantastic!!! I couldn't figure out what the problem was. You saved me from madness!! Thanks again

Comment: haha! Been there, done that. Bought the 'I am mad'_t-shirt. Glad to help out.